# Dicom Router implementation using dcm4chee kit

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I am very new to DICOM. I want to develop a DICOM router. 
For example I have PACS `server1` and PACS `server2`. I want to send some specific study from server1 to sever2.

How can I do that using dcm4chee kit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C-Move Dicom SOP Class. You can use `dcm4che-tool-movescu` from dcm4che3 or older `dcm4che-tool-dcmmv` from dcm4che2.

Both utilities allows you to run a C-Move as SCU. With this operation you can send any study from one PACS to another AET.

Keep in mind that C-Move only specify the AET of receiving system, thus, source PACS must known this AET as well as host and port data.

Comment: Hey thanks, I have done that :), now I want to search the server.  if  for example user enters a patient id to serach, then my app populate a table with all the metadata  relating to that id , such as id, name, accession number e.tc. if tha study id exists in the dicom server, How can this be done using dcm4chee kit.

Comment: Sure, why don't you ask anither question? Tag it as dicom dcm4che and sure you will find answer you want :)